# How do i reuse a state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js.
and I tried to use a function that has boolean, and I want to reuse just one function to another button.
so I tried like this:

```js
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [show1, setShow1] = useState(false);
  const [show2, setShow2] = useState(false);

  

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setShow(true);
    setShow1(false);
    setShow2(false);
  };
  const handleOnClick1 = () => {
    setShow1(true);
    setShow(false);
    setShow2(false);
  };
  const handleOnClick2 = () => {
    setShow2(true);
    setShow(false);
    setShow1(false);
  };
```

```js
 const panels = ["1+3", "2+2", "3+1"];
  const getPanel = e => {
    switch (e) {
      case "1+3":
        handleOnClick();
        break;
      case "2+2":
        handleOnClick1();
        break;
      case "3+1":
        handleOnClick2();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  const panelList = panels.map(panel => (
    <div onClick={() => getPanel(panel)}>
      <h1>Panel{panel}</h1>
    </div>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <Main>{panelList}</Main>
      {show && <One />}
      {show1 && <Two />}
      {show2 && <Three />}
    </div>
```

the question is
How can i use one useState instead of making another one ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always just going to have one button showing, you can go ahead and just maintain the ID of that button in state rather than a bunch of boolean states.

Furthermore, it might be nice to make just one click handler. You could do this a bunch of ways, such as using the clicked button's ID, or you could do a higher-order function and pass the clicked ID directly. Here is the latter approach:

```js
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState();

  const handleOnClick = (id) => () => {
    setShow(id);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick(1)}>Show 1</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick(2)}>Show 2</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick(3)}>Show 3</button>
      {show === 1 && <One />}
      {show === 2 && <Two />}
      {show === 3 && <Three />}
    </>
  );
}
```